# Apex: can't create new application

Tags: oracle-apex

Im using apex 19.1 and oracle 18c.

few months ago we have upgraded our apex version from 18.2 to 19.1 After that we were able to create, copy pages/applications.

recently we ran into a problem, we are not able anymore to create or even copy pages/applications.

for example when I try to create new page, this error appears.

[image]

when try to copy page

[image]

and finally when I try to create a new app. the application will be created but it has only a global page, and this error appears::

> ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_CREATE_APP_V3", line 3686 ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_CREATE_APP_V3", line 3686 ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_CREATE_APP_V3", line 3762 ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_CREATE_APP_V3", line 4623 ORA-06512: at line 38

[image: or]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a fresh install or have you upgraded from a previous version of APEX? Could you create new applications before or did this problem appear at the first time you tried to create a new application on this instance? Can you copy existing applications or install one of the packaged applications supplied by Oracle?

Comment: its an upgraded from a previous version (Apex 18), before upgrading I have created many applications, after upgrading I didnt try to create a new application until last week.
copying and installing from packaged applications working with no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you in that case. I would suggest you to ask the people at the [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/application_express), the APEX community here at stackoverflow is small. Add the additional information from your comment to your post.